# How track changes in textarea in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I want show button Save when value in textarea changes?

```
<template lang="pug">
.modal-task(:style="{display: showDetailsModal}")
    .modal-task-details
        .task()
            .description
                |description: {{task.description1}}
                textarea(v-model='task.description1')
        button(v-show="showSaveButton" @click="saveTask()") Save
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'task-details-modal',
  props: ['showDetailsModal', 'task'],
  data () {
    return {
      showSaveButton: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
</script>
```

What method i need to create?
As far as i understand i need to create variable where i will save
initial value and if initial value !== task.description1 change showSaveButton: false on true
How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<template lang="pug">
.modal-task(:style="{display: showDetailsModal}")
    .modal-task-details
        .task()
            .description
                |description: {{task.description1}}
                textarea(v-model='task.description1')
        button(v-show="showSaveButton" @click="saveTask()") Save
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'task-details-modal',
  props: ['showDetailsModal', 'task'],
  data () {
    return {
      showSaveButton: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  watch{
    task.description1 (New){
      this.showSaveButton = true
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

or:

```js
<template lang="pug">
.modal-task(:style="{display: showDetailsModal}")
    .modal-task-details
        .task()
            .description
                |description: {{task.description1}}
                textarea(v-model='task.description1' @change="handleChange")
        button(v-show="showSaveButton" @click="saveTask()") Save
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'task-details-modal',
  props: ['showDetailsModal', 'task'],
  data () {
    return {
      showSaveButton: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange(){
        this.showSaveButton = true
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

both of two ways you can try it